# Creating PFX File for AWS

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am writing a VB.net application to communicate with AWS (Amazon Web Services) No problem getting that working. But I need to us a PFX file for the certificate. I did find instructions on creating the PFX using the following Open SSL command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out YOURPFXFILE.pfx -inkey *****-private.pem.key -in *****-certificate.pem.crt

and if i use that file in my app every thing is working.

I decided to try to programmatically create the PFX. I have tried doing that using the following code:

```
 Try
        Dim certificate As New X509Certificate2("6469d8cccd-certificate.pem.crt")
        Dim certificateData As Byte() = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "MyPassword")
        File.WriteAllBytes("MyCert.pfx", certificateData)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This created the PFX file but if I use that it fails.

My question is, Should i expect the file not to work because I ues the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates instead of Open SSL?

Or is my code incorrect? if so can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Any reason you want to create the certificate programmatically now since the OpenSSL generated certificate and it works?

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce the work for the end user. Instead of telling them to go and download Open SSL and explaining the the command line arguments. I prefer that my application creates the pfx file for them.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what the question asked, but here is a library that converts PFX to PEM using VB.NET. It would be possible to observe the code and learn how to do the reverse with the libeay32 OpenSSL API for an observant programmer.

Thus, you could create a PFX by using similar functions as in the code below and the fact that the following is the opposite of `PKCS12_parse()` which converts pkcs12 or pfx format into pem or der format, `d2i_PKCS12()` converts pem into pfx.

```
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
PKCS12 * 
d2i_PKCS12(PKCS12 **val_out, const unsigned char **der_in, long length);
```

https://git.motes.camp/web/index.php?p=libCurlVB.NET-native.git&a=blob&h=d5d25c707e29dc2f359043a9cae6581ee5fb4b3c&hb=160db2d8aca2899e1379fd1048cf650bad37c3e9&f=LibCurlDecl.vb#l412

```vb
'''Return Type: int, 0 = success or 1 = failure
'''PFXinfile: String
'''password: String
'''PEMoutfile: String
Public Shared Function PFXtoPEM(ByVal PFXinfile As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal PEMoutfile As String) As Integer
    Dim fp As IntPtr
    Dim p12 As IntPtr
    Dim cert As X509
    Dim ca As stack_st_X509
    Dim StdErr As IntPtr
    Const errbufSize = 8192
    Dim errBuf As IntPtr

    Dim GCHpkey As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(New IntPtr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim GCHcert As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(New IntPtr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim GCHca As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(New IntPtr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim pPkey As IntPtr = GCHpkey.AddrOfPinnedObject
    Dim pCert As IntPtr = GCHcert.AddrOfPinnedObject
    Dim pCa As IntPtr = GCHca.AddrOfPinnedObject

    fp = fopen(PFXinfile, "rb")
    If fp.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Error opening file: ", PFXinfile), "Error Converting PFX to PEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return 1
    End If

    ERR_load_crypto_strings()
    StdErr = freopen("NUL", "a", IntPtr.op_Explicit(__iob_func.ToInt64() + (Marshal.SizeOf(New FILEp) * 2)))
    errBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(errbufSize)
    memset(errBuf, Asc(vbNullChar), errbufSize)
    setvbuf(StdErr, errBuf, _IOFBF, errbufSize)

    OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf()

    Try
        p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, IntPtr.Zero)
        If p12.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then Throw New SEHException("d2i_PKCS12_fp didn't throw but also didn't succeed")
    Catch ex As SEHException
        ERR_print_errors_fp(StdErr)
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Error reading PKCS#12 file. " & vbNewLine, Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errBuf)), "Error Converting PFX to PEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return 1
    End Try

    fclose(fp)

    Try
        PKCS12_parse(p12, password, pPkey, pCert, pCa)
        If IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pPkey)).Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then Throw New SEHException("PKCS12_parse didn't throw but also didn't succeed")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ERR_print_errors_fp(StdErr)
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Error parsing PKCS#12 file, check pfx password. " & vbNewLine, Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errBuf)), "Error Converting PFX to PEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return 1
    End Try

    PKCS12_free(p12)

    fp = fopen(PEMoutfile, "w")
    If fp.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Error opening file: ", PEMoutfile), "Error Converting PFX to PEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return 1
    End If


    If Not IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pPkey)).Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        fprintf(fp, "****Private Key****" & vbNewLine)
        PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pPkey)), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    End If


    If Not IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert)).Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        fprintf(fp, "***User Certificate***" & vbNewLine)
        fprintf(fp, "subject=")
        fprintf(fp, X509_NAME_oneline(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert)) + 20))), 0, 0))
        fprintf(fp, vbNewLine & "issuer=")
        fprintf(fp, X509_NAME_oneline(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert)) + 12))), 0, 0))
        fprintf(fp, vbNewLine)
        PEM_write_X509_AUX(fp, IntPtr.op_Explicit((Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert))))
    End If


    If Not IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert)).Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        ca = Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCa)), GetType(stack_st_X509))
        fprintf(fp, "****CA Certificates****" & vbNewLine)

        For i = 0 To ca.stack.num - 1

            cert = Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(ca.stack.data.ToInt32 + 4 * i))), GetType(X509))
            Dim certGChandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(cert.cert_info, GCHandleType.Pinned)
            Dim pCertInfo As IntPtr = certGChandle.AddrOfPinnedObject

            fprintf(fp, "subject=")
            fprintf(fp, X509_NAME_oneline(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCertInfo) + 20))), 0, 0))
            fprintf(fp, vbNewLine & "issuer=")
            fprintf(fp, X509_NAME_oneline(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCertInfo) + 12))), 0, 0))
            fprintf(fp, vbNewLine)
            PEM_write_X509_AUX(fp, IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Explicit(ca.stack.data.ToInt32 + 4 * i))))
            certGChandle.Free()

        Next

    End If

    fclose(fp)

    EVP_PKEY_free(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pPkey)))
    X509_free(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCert)))
    sk_free(IntPtr.op_Explicit(Marshal.ReadInt32(pCa)))

    GCHca.Free()
    GCHcert.Free()
    GCHpkey.Free()

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(errBuf)

    Return 0

End Function
```